# How to use sum function in SAS

Tags: function, sas, sum

I think there're other ways to sum of all cells. I'd just like to learn how to use sum function. Please give me some advice about "sum(y)" following program in SAS.

```
data dt00;
 input X Y @@;
 cards;
 1 3 2 5
;
run;

data dt01;
 set dt00;
 z+x+sum(y);
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summing along row** - sum and arrays.

Using the sum function:

```
data want;
    set dt00;
    sum=sum(x, y);
run;
```

You could also use `sum=sum(of _numeric_);` - this will sum all numeric columns in case too many to list.

Using arrays:

```
data want;
    set dt00;
    array s {*} _numeric_;
    sum=sum(of s[*]);
run;
```

---

**Summing along column** - here we are only interested in the total sum of the column, so we select the last row. You can do this with the combination of the `end=` option in the set statement and the if statement.

```
data want;
    set dt00 end=eof; 
    sum_x + x;
    sum_y + y;
    
    if eof then output;
    keep sum:;
run;
```

In case you have a lot of columns I would advise you to compute the columns total using other SAS procedures (e.g. using the means procedure).

```
proc means data=dt00 noprint;
    var _numeric_;
    output out=want(drop=_type_ _freq_) sum= / autoname;
run;
```

---

**Summing all cells** - here we use the same trick as for summing along column as we are only interesting in the total sum of all cell.

```
data want;
    set dt00 end=eof;
    sum + x + y;

    if eof then output;
    keep sum;
run;
```

The sum statement `sum + x + y` implies that the sum variable is automatically retained and that all missing values are considered as 0.

Put simply, this is the equivalent of

```
data want;
    set dt00 end=eof;
    retain sum;
    sum = sum(sum,x,y);

    if eof then output;
    keep sum;
run;
```

Comment: very helpful! thank you so much!